# Emit with ack SocketIO with iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, socket.io

I'm trying to make an emit with a callback, but it seems like the server doesn't recognize the call back function as a function. I have looked up the documentation, and to my knowledge the code should work.

This is the error I'm getting: `TypeError: callBack is not a function`

Here is the client code:

```
socket?.emitWithAck("connectUsername", username).timingOut(after: 2, callback: { (data) in
            
        print(data)
    })
```

And server code:

```
socket.on("connectUsername", function(username, callBack)
    {
        //Do stuff with username here...

        var id = socket.id
        callBack(id);
     });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

as @kiddosrails mention problem is the timeout 2 seconds is less time to execute,  you can set timeout **0** which refer as not time out. Hope this answer will help you.

```
     socket.emitWithAck("connectUsername", username).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
      print(data)    
    }
```

Comment: The server console is still getting the same error: TypeError: callBack is not a function

Comment: can you share console log of socket.io ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see callback as a parameter of `timingOut` in documentation. Following should work:

```
socket.emitWithAck("connectUsername", username).timingOut(after: 20) { data in 
  print(data)
}
```

If above does not work, check what *exactly* is callBack by changing it to following:

```
socket.on("connectUsername", function(username, callBack)
    {
        //Do stuff with username here...

        var id = socket.id
        console.log(callBack.toString());
     });
```

Comment: I will test it as soon as I'm home

Comment: If I delete the callBack parameter in the client, the compiler will complain and suggest to add it back.

If I try to check the string of 'callBack' the following happens in the console:

/Users/xxxx/Documents/socket-training/index.js:69
       console.log(callBack.toString());
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Code**

```
socket?.emitWithAck("connectUsername", data).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
            print(data) 
        }
```

**Server Code**

```
var io = socketIO.listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('a user connected..!!!!!');
    client.on('connectUsername', function(username, callBack){
        var id = socket.id
        callback({
        ID:id,
        Message: "Successfully."
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The server console is still getting the same error: TypeError: callBack is not a function

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if you still face any issue

Comment: This is exactly how my code is written out, I can connect users successfully and do other stuff, but as soon as I try to do an emit with a callback it crashes.

Comment: would you please confirm which socket.io version you have used on server and iOS side

Comment: Server: socket.io@2.1.1   -   
Client: 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

In your server code:

```
socket.on("connectUsername", function(username, callBack)
    {
        //Do stuff with username here...

        var id = socket.id
        callBack = ({id});
     });
```

That's because callback is not defined like an object so you can defined it like one.

Comment: Please mention the reasons for your approach so others can understand it easily